# Count Uppercase letters Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I can only find answers on this using vba or java.
I am taking a user input from a textbox and counting the number of uppercase characters given.
This is homework so if you could even point me in the right direction I would be much obliged.

```
Private Sub BtnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles BtnGo.Click
    Dim Phrase As String
    Dim CharPhrase As Char 'Convert Phrase to char for sting comparison
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0 'used to measure the characters in textbox
    Dim Caps As Integer = 0 'How many capitals are there?
    Phrase = TxtboxPhrase.Text
    If Phrase.Length <= 15 Then
        MsgBox("There must be at least 15 characters in textbox")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    While Counter <= Phrase.Length
'Code for counting here
    End While
    MsgBox("There are " & Caps & " capital letters in the current phrase")
    Call ProgQuit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a thought, but a FOR loop is probably a better fit for this solution (instead of a WHILE loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a C# developer but here is the algorithm I would use in VB.NET:

```
Private Function CountUpper(str As String) As Integer
Dim ucount As Integer = 0

For Each c As Char In str
    Dim charCode As Integer = AscW(c)

    If charCode >= 65 AndAlso charCode < 91 Then
        ucount += 1
    End If
Next

Return ucount
End Function
```

EDIT: I ran this code through a C# to VB converter so there may be some issues. I just fixed one obvious one.

Comment: There. The code was thrown together untested but at least I got the char codes right (I hope).

Comment: @M.Babcock What about characters other then ASCII? I think about japanese or cyrillic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using VB.NET here, it looks like you are, but I code C#, not VB so I'm not sure. You will want to iterate through the string. You can do this easily, as `string` implements `IEnumerable`.

There's two methods you could use to test for capitalisation. You could either cast it to an integer and see if it is higher than the integer value of A or lower than the integer value of Z. You might also consider comparing the string to an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a substring of a string with `substr`. For example, the third character of your string can be obtained with:

```
Dim StrCh as String
: :
StrCh = Phrase.Substring (2,1)
```

It's `2` for the third character, since the first character is at position `0`. The `1` is the number of characters to extract, starting from that position.

Then you can check if a character is uppercase by checking if the character changes when you uppercase it - if it doesn't, then the character is *already* uppercase. Something like:

```
If StrCh = StrCh.ToUpper() Then
    ... is uppercase
End If
```

Those hints should be enough for you to complete your work.

Comment: Doesn't ToUpper() require a parameter?  A "Culture" object, or something like that?

Comment: @Bryce: no, it doesn't _need_ it. The current culture is used where you don't supply one. You _can_ supply a culture if you wish to use one other than the current one but the use cases for that are relatively rare (but not non-existant). One tends to usually use only the current culture.

Comment: what is the 1 in "StrCh = Phrase.Substring (2,1)"?

Comment: @Zombian: it's the number of characters to extract: `"Formaldehyde".substring(3,4)` gives you `"mald"`.

Comment: I get an error that "No accessible ToUpper accepts that many arguments.  Could this be an issue because I am using vb2005?

Comment: I tried it in vs2010 and got the same thing.  That's where I was going with my initial comment.

Comment: @Zombian: sorry, my bad. Take off the parentheses `()` and try again. You're using an older version of NET where I think (from distant memory) the call was slightly different. VS2010 however works fine with `ToUpper()`. Make sure that the object you're using is a `String` one.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you can do:

```
Dim Caps As Integer = (From x As Char In Phrase.ToCharArray() Where Char.IsUpper(x) Select x).ToArray().Count
```